# Using Paperclip to upload files to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I've been trying to setup Paperclip to allow us to send files to S3. I'm not very familiar with S3 or Paperclip, so I've been following the tutorial here at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3 but I've run into some issues. As far as I can tell, I've followed the directions exactly, but I keep receiving the error when I click the submit button after attaching a file (in this case, SpringPictures_FrontSlider.jpg):

**"Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in DprojectsController#create"**

**"No handler found for "SpringPictures_FrontSlider.jpg"**

and it has a problem with this line in the controller:

**"@dproject = Dproject.new(dproject_params)"**

I'm wondering what's going wrong. Thanks for any assistance! Here's all of my code as well- just because I don't know exactly where the problem is occurring. The scaffold I'm using is "dprojects" and I migrated the attachment to simply be called "attachment".

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.6.0'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
```

config/environment/production.rb:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['ACCESS_KEY'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
    }
  }
```

dproject.rb (model):

```
class Dproject < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :attachment, styles: {
        thumb: '100x100>',
        square: '200x200#',
        medium: '300x300>'
    }

    validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Migration:

```
class AddAttachementToDprojects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :dprojects, :attachment
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :dprojects, :attachment
  end
end
```

_formNew.html.erb (view):

```
<%= form_for @dproject, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary", id: "submit" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

dprojects_controller.rb (controller):

```
def create
    @dproject = Dproject.new(dproject_params)

    if @dproject.save
      redirect_to @dproject, notice: 'File successfully attached'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
end

private

def dproject_params
      params.require(:dproject).permit(:scode, :description, :requested_by, :assigned_to, :completed_at, :order_num, :contact, :contact_email, :ptype, :due_date, :must_date, :print_date, :proofs_out, :proofs_in, :status, :delivery_type, :route, :delivery_date, :tracking_number, :shipping_instructions, :invoicing, :delivered, :printing_instructions, :project_changes, :invoice_quantity, :invoice_price, :project_path, :attachment)
    end
end
```

config/initializers/paperclip.rb:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :s3
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_protocol] = 'https'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] = 
  { :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['ACCESS_KEY'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['SECRET_KEY'] }
```

Comment: share your config/initializers/paperclip.rb as well

Comment: I just edited it! Hopefully that helps